# How to show selected custom object data in community napili template?

Tags: community-builder

I just setup a napili template in the community builder. I wish to show data to the user from a custom object based on a 9 digit number that they enter. So I want the first screen to have just a text box and a button to enter the number and submit. Once done, it should show the classes that the user is scheduled to attend. How to do this in the Napili template? How to setup a simple screen #1, then the second screen with the info that pertains to the user?

I haven seen any tutorials that show this. If anyone know of any please share.

Thanks